# Python exit while loop and print only once

Tags: python, time, while-loop, discord.py

I wanna loop "time" untill 12:30 but print only once. How would I do this?

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    reminder.start()
    print("rdy")


@tasks.loop()
async def reminder():
    i= 0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start= now.replace(hour=22, minute=45, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if now<start:
        await client.get_channel(852950484842315786).send(f"works")
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yCIl.png)

Comment: `while i == 0` always will be true, because you don't change the `i` value in this loop. It is gonna be a infinity loop

Comment: If you wanna print only once then use break to exit the loop and print after that

Comment: @blazej what could I use instead?

Comment: @barny either I'm doing smthn wrong, but It doesn't print after I use break

Comment: remi**N**der? you do not break anywhere ... nor do you print anywhere in the code.

Comment: If you user break, you exit the whole loop iteration. Stackoverflow is not a website where you can learn programming basics.

Comment: @remiNder no but I tried that already, thats why I'm here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the time.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def remider():
    i= 0
    o= 0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start= now.replace(hour=12, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if now<start:
        await client.get_channel(852950484842315786).send(f"works")
```

One thing is that at the end of the file you have to start the loop by

```
reminder.start()
```